# Whole page scrolls on top when I use jQuery scrollLeft only for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to have div, which I can scroll horizontally by clicking links outside of this div. (one for left scroll and one for right scroll).

I used jQuery animate and scrollLeft. Everything looks good, but only problem is: when I click on link for make a scroll with div, whole page is scrolled on top too. I found some similar topics here, but no solutions what I can apply on my problem (or maybe what I am able to apply on my problem).

Please be considerate, this is my first question here. :-)

Thanks

```js
function move_right() {
    var current = $('.thumbnail-scroll').scrollLeft();
    var maximal = document.getElementById("thumbnail-scroll").scrollWidth;
    var visible = document.getElementById("thumbnail-scroll").offsetWidth;
    var move;

    if ((current + visible) < maximal) {
        $('.thumbnail-scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=' + 470
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function move_left() {
    var current = $('.thumbnail-scroll').scrollLeft();

    if (current > 0) {
        $('.thumbnail-scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=' + 470
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
.thumbnail-scroll  {
         height: 150px;
         overflow-x: auto;
         white-space: nowrap;
         overflow:hidden;
         background-color:  #cc33ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style=" background-color:   #6666ff; line-height: 230px;">
         <div> some content </div>
         <div> some content </div>
         <div> some content </div>
      </div>
      <div style=" display: flex; ">
         <div class="move-left" style="width: 150px; line-height: 145px; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a onclick="move_left()" href="#">
            <span> LEFT </span>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbnail-scroll" id="thumbnail-scroll">
            <span> some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content </span>
         </div>
         <div class="move-right" style="width: 150px;  line-height: 145px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <a href="#" onclick="move_right()">
            <span> RIGHT </span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is due to setting the `href` to `#`. It is the normal behaviour when clicking on hash links (*not found in the page*).

Just removing the attribute fixes the problem. (*an alternative would be to bind the handlers through jQuery and use `preventDefault()` on the passed event*)

```js
function move_right() {
    var current = $('.thumbnail-scroll').scrollLeft();
    var maximal = document.getElementById("thumbnail-scroll").scrollWidth;
    var visible = document.getElementById("thumbnail-scroll").offsetWidth;
    var move;

    if ((current + visible) < maximal) {


        $('.thumbnail-scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: '+=' + 470
        }, 1000);

    }
}



function move_left() {
    var current = $('.thumbnail-scroll').scrollLeft();


    if (current > 0) {


        $('.thumbnail-scroll').animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=' + 470
        }, 1000);

    }
}
```

```css
.thumbnail-scroll  {
         height: 150px;
         overflow-x: auto;
         white-space: nowrap;
         overflow:hidden;
         background-color:  #cc33ff;
         }

a[onclick]{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style=" background-color:   #6666ff; line-height: 230px;">
         <div> some content </div>
         <div> some content </div>
         <div> some content </div>
      </div>
      <div style=" display: flex; ">
         <div class="move-left" style="width: 150px; line-height: 145px; padding-right: 10px;">
            <a onclick="move_left()">
            <span> LEFT </span>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbnail-scroll" id="thumbnail-scroll">
            <span> some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content some content </span>
         </div>
         <div class="move-right" style="width: 150px;  line-height: 145px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <a onclick="move_right()">
            <span> RIGHT </span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I am ashamed: D
Thank you for answer